# Proper TypeScript type for creating JSX element from string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that I want to default to being rendered as an `h2`. I'd like the consumer to be able to specify a different element if they desire. The code below results in the error:

`TS2604 - JSX element type 'ElementType' does not have any construct or call signatures`

I think I understand why it fails, TS is expecting to render a React node. For clarity, React *is* able to render elements referenced as strings as long as the variable begins with a capital letter (this being a JSX requirement). I've done this before successfully in vanilla JS + React, I just don't know how to satisfy TypeScript.

How can I get TypeScript to render this without resorting to `elementType?: any`

```
import React, {ReactNode} from 'react'

interface Props {
    children: ReactNode;
    elementType?: string;
}

export default function ({children, elementType: ElementType = 'h2'}: Props): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <ElementType>{children}</ElementType>
    );
}
```

Comment: Related [When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, a bit about JSX. It is just a syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`, which is a JavaScript expression.

With this knowledge in mind, now let's take a look at why TypeScript complains. You define `elementType` as `string`, however, when you actually use it, it becomes a JavaScript expression. `string` type of course doesn't have any construct or call signature.

Now we know the root cause. In React, there is a type called `FunctionComponent`. As you can guess, it is a function expression, which is what we want. So you can define `elementType` as `string | FunctionComponent`. This should make TypeScript happy :)

FYI: the recommended way to define prop typing is by doing this:

```
const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks for sharing the recommended way to define prop typing, I'm still learning the ins and outs of TS!

Answer (score 27):

Use `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements`:

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  elementType?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements;
}

export default function ({ children, elementType: ElementType = 'h2' }: Props): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <ElementType>{children}</ElementType>
  );
}
```

Comment: best solution if your root element should be an intrinsic type - gives auto-completion and everything.

Answer (score 5):

I was making a `<Text>` component and wanted to narrow the set of possible HTML tags that the developer could pass in to just "text based" elements like `span`, `p`, `h1`, etc.

So I had something like:

```
// Narrow the tags to p, span, h1, etc
type AS = Extract<keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements, 'p' | 'span' | 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5'>;

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  as: AS;
  // ... other props here
}

export function Text(props: Props) {  

  // Render the text with the appropriate HTML tag.
  return (
    <HTMLTag as={props.as}>
      {props.children}
    </HTMLTag>
  );
}

interface HTMLTagProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLOrSVGElement> {
  as: AS;
}

function HTMLTag({ as: As, ...otherProps }: HTMLTagProps) {
  return <As {...otherProps} />;
}
```

Comment: Bingo! I wanted to restrict what was an overly permissive prop of type  `React.ElementType` in a refactor pass because it should only accept headings. Using the generic of `React.ElementType` wasn't right... A quick search brought me to your answer and its exactly what I needed. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

if you just want the type of **any** jsx element you can use

```
type jsxType = JSX.IntrinsicElements[keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements]
```

this will accept any jsx element.

Comment: Noob here trying to understand...so e.g. that should be `type divType = JSX.IntrinsicElements["div"]`? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me given the component is defined like this:

```
interface LabelProps {
        ...
        tag?: React.ElementType | string;
    }

const Label: VFC<LabelProps> = ({
       ...other props...
        tag: Element = 'span',
    }) => (
        <Element>
            {children}
        </Element>
    );
```

and prop types:

```
Label.propTypes = {
    ...
    tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.elementType, PropTypes.string]),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReactElement`:

```
import type {ReactElement} from 'react';
const HelloWorld = function HelloWorld({ prop: string }): ReactElement {
    return <div>{prop}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That is not going to work, you need to use React.createElement(). https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

Something like this

```
  import React, {ReactNode} from 'react'

interface Props {
    children: ReactNode,
    elementType?: string,
}

export default function ({children, elementType: ElementType = 'h2'}: Props): JSX.Element {

    return React.createElement(elementType, {}, children); 
}
```

Comment: With respect, this _does_ work. What I posted is just syntactic sugar for your solution. This isn't an issue with React, it is an issue with TS.

Answer (score -6):

for me I added `// @ts-ignore` above the line that complained and it works

Comment: The whole point of TypeScript is that it allows you to have guarantees about how your code works. Ignoring type errors is like ignoring a check engine light in a car. It may work, or it may blow up. This is not a solution.

Comment: Or you could just not use typescript and the problem goes away