# When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently migrating a React application to TypeScript. So far, this works pretty well, but I have a problem with the return types of my `render` functions, specifically in my functional components.

I have always used `JSX.Element` as the return type, now this doesn't work any more if a component decides to *not* render anything, i.e. returns `null`, since `null` is not a valid value for `JSX.Element`. This was the beginning of my journey. I searched the web and found that you should use `ReactNode` instead, which includes `null` and a few other things that can happen.

However, when creating a functional component, TypeScript complains about the `ReactNode` type. Again, after some searching I found, that for functional components you should use `ReactElement` instead. However, if I do so, the compatibility issue is gone, but now TypeScript again complains about `null` not being a valid value.

To cut a long story short, I have three questions:

1. What is the difference between `JSX.Element`, `ReactNode` and `ReactElement`?
2. Why do the `render` methods of class components return `ReactNode`, but functional components return `ReactElement`?
3. How do I solve this with respect to `null`?

Comment: I'm surprised this would come up, since usually you don't need to specify the return type with components. What type signature are you doing for the components? Should look something like `class Example extends Component<ExampleProps> {` for classes, and `const Example: FunctionComponent<ExampleProps> = (props) => {` for function components (where `ExampleProps` is an interface for the expected props). And then these types have enough information that the return type can be inferred.

Comment: The types are defined [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/eafef8bd049017b3998939de2edbab5d8a96423b/types/react/v15/index.d.ts#L187)

Comment: @NicholasTower Our linting rules enforce explicitly providing the return type, and that's why this comes up (which IMHO is a good thing, because you think way more about what you do, which helps understanding, than if you just let the compiler infer everything).

Comment: Fair enough, i didn't think of linting rules.

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for the link, but I don't think that this answers my questions.

Answer (score 810, accepted):

> What is the difference between JSX.Element, ReactNode and ReactElement?

A [`ReactElement`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L318-L325) is an object with `type`, `props`, and `key` properties:

```js
interface ReactElement<
  P = any,
  T extends
    | string
    | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string
    | JSXElementConstructor<any>,
> {
  type: T;
  props: P;
  key: string | null;
}
```

A [`JSX.Element`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L4235) is a `ReactElement<any, any>`. It exists as various libraries can implement `JSX` in their own way:

```js
declare global {
  // …
  namespace JSX {
    // …
    interface Element extends React.ReactElement<any, any> {}
    // …
  }
  // …
}
```

A [`ReactPortal`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L368-L370) is a `ReactElement` with a `children` property:

```js
interface ReactPortal extends ReactElement {
  children: ReactNode;
}
```

A [`ReactNode`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L467-L478) is a `ReactElement`, `string`, `number`, `Iterable<ReactNode>`, `ReactPortal`, `boolean`, `null`, or `undefined`:

```js
type ReactNode =
  | ReactElement
  | string
  | number
  | Iterable<ReactNode>
  | ReactPortal
  | boolean
  | null
  | undefined;
```

Example:

```html
<div> // <- ReactElement
  <Component> // <- ReactElement
    {condition && 'text'} // <- ReactNode
  </Component>
</div>
```

> Why do the render methods of class components return ReactNode, but function components return ReactElement?

This is due to [historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840095/5260024).

A [`Component.render`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v17/index.d.ts#L433-L507) returns a `ReactNode`:

```js
class Component<P, S> {
  // …
  render(): ReactNode;
  // …
}
```

A [`FunctionComponent`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v17/index.d.ts#L543-L549) returns a `ReactElement<any, any> | null`:

```js
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P> | undefined;
  contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any> | undefined;
  defaultProps?: Partial<P> | undefined;
  displayName?: string | undefined;
}
```

> How do I solve this with respect to null?

Type it as `ReactElement | null` just as React does. Or let TypeScript infer the type.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This perfectly answers question 1, but still leaves questions 2 and 3 unanswered. Can you provide some guidance on them, too, please?

Comment: @goloRoden sure, I'm just a bit tired right now and it takes some time to scroll through the types on a mobile ... ;)

Comment: Hi @JonasWilms. Regarding "They don't. ReactComponent is defined as: render(): JSX.Element | null | false;", where are you seeing that? It looks like it returns ReactNode to me (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bdfdaf7fef18e267ed2df2e37e4bf81y685706eb2/types/react/index.d.ts#L443 )

Also minor typo, I think `ReactComponent` should be `React.Component` or `Component`.

Comment: @MarkDoliner Weird, I could swear that I copied that type out of the file ... Whatever, you're totally right, I'll edit

Comment: Guys is there any official documentation of the react &&  typescript somewhere on the web?

Answer (score 101):

> 1.) What is the difference between JSX.Element, ReactNode and ReactElement?

**ReactElement and JSX.Element**
are the result of invoking [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement) directly or via JSX transpilation. It is an object with `type`, `props` and `key`. [`JSX.Element`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/24f1d0c82da2d898acd03fbb3e692eba3c431f82/types/react/index.d.ts#L2882) is `ReactElement`, whose `props` and `type` have type `any`, so they are more or less the same.

```
const jsx = <div>hello</div>
const ele = React.createElement("div", null, "hello");
```

**ReactNode** is used as return type for `render()` in class components. It also is the default type for `children` attribute with [`PropsWithChildren`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/24f1d0c82da2d898acd03fbb3e692eba3c431f82/types/react/index.d.ts#L773).

```
const Comp: FunctionComponent = props => <div>{props.children}</div> 
// children?: React.ReactNode
```

It looks more complicated in the [React type declarations](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2034c45/types/react/index.d.ts#L203), but is *equivalent* to:

```
type ReactNode = {} | null | undefined;
// super type `{}` has absorbed *all* other types, which are sub types of `{}`
// so it is a very "broad" type (I don't want to say useless...)
```

You can assign almost everything to `ReactNode`. I usually would prefer stronger types, but there might be some valid cases to use it.

---

> 2.) Why do the render methods of class components return ReactNode, but function components return ReactElement?

**tl;dr:** It is a current TS type incompatibility [not related to core React](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699).

- TS class component: returns `ReactNode` with `render()`, more permissive than React/JS
- TS function component: returns `JSX.Element | null`, more restrictive than React/JS

In principle, `render()` in React/JS class components [supports the same return types](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12155#issuecomment-363089187) as a function component. With regard to TS, the different types are a type inconsistency still kept due to historical reasons and the need for backwards-compatibility.

Ideally a [valid return type](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) would probably look more like this:

```
type ComponentReturnType = ReactElement | Array<ComponentReturnType> | string | number 
  | boolean | null // Note: undefined is invalid
```

---

> 3.) How do I solve this with respect to null?

Some options:

```
// Use type inference; inferred return type is `JSX.Element | null`
const MyComp1 = ({ condition }: { condition: boolean }) =>
    condition ? <div>Hello</div> : null

// Use explicit function return types; Add `null`, if needed
const MyComp2 = (): JSX.Element => <div>Hello</div>; 
const MyComp3 = (): React.ReactElement => <div>Hello</div>;  
// Option 3 is equivalent to 2 + we don't need to use a global (JSX namespace)

// Use built-in `FunctionComponent` or `FC` type
const MyComp4: React.FC<MyProps> = () => <div>Hello</div>;
```

*Note:* Avoiding `React.FC` [won't save](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wFgAoCtCAOwGd4BhXMOAXjgAoBKdgPgIAJJABsREMuWr14AQTCsOPfnAA8zcHAD0ArVrgApAMoANOKKQgkNeDACeYJHADkDKMBoBzZ3GB04NBDwKHDSbgCuGNBwmOE0GMC0MdHGZhZWNnQAdEA) you from the `JSX.Element | null` return type restriction.

Create React App recently [dropped `React.FC`](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) from its template, as it has some quirks like an implicit [`{children?: ReactNode}`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2034c45/types/react/index.d.ts#L787) type definition. So using `React.FC` sparingly might be preferable.

In edge cases, you can add a type assertion or Fragments as workaround:

```
const MyCompFragment: FunctionComponent = () => <>"Hello"</>
const MyCompCast: FunctionComponent = () => "Hello" as any 
// alternative to `as any`: `as unknown as JSX.Element | null`
```

Comment: This Answer is great. However, I use React 18 in 2022. The `ReactFragment` is `Iterable<ReactNode>` now, there is no type `{}` anymore.

Answer (score 62):

**ReactElement** is the type for elements in React, either created via **JSX** or **React.createElement**.

```
const a = <div/> // this is a ReactElement
```

**ReactNode** is wider, it can be text, number, boolean, null, undefined, a portal, a ReactElement, or an array of ReactNodes.
It represents **anything that React can render**.

```
const a = (
  <div>
     hello {[1, "world", true]} // this is a ReactNode
  </div>
)
```

`JSX.Element` is an internal hook for Typescript. It is *set equal to* ReactElement to tell Typescript that every JSX expressions should be typed as ReactElements. But if we'd use Preact, or other technologies using JSX it would be set to something else.

**Functional components** return `ReactElement | null`, so it cannot return a bare string or an array of ReactElements. It is a [known](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33006) [limitation](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20544). The workaround is to use **Fragments** :

```
const Foo = () => {
  return <>hello world!</>  // this works
}
```

**Class components'** render function return `ReactNode`, so there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Nice answer. Looks like Functional Components now [can return `ReactNode` since 18.2.8 / Jun 2023](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/65135) (but it appears this can be buggy depending on what version(s) of Typescript a project uses)

Comment: Yes the problem worked around with fragments doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Great explanation of `ReactNode`

Answer (score 17):

https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#useful-react-prop-type-examples

```
export declare interface AppProps {
  children1: JSX.Element; // bad, doesnt account for arrays
  children2: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]; // meh, doesn't accept strings
  children3: React.ReactChildren; // despite the name, not at all an appropriate type; it is a utility
  children4: React.ReactChild[]; // better, accepts array children
  children: React.ReactNode; // best, accepts everything (see edge case below)
  functionChildren: (name: string) => React.ReactNode; // recommended function as a child render prop type
  style?: React.CSSProperties; // to pass through style props
  onChange?: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>; // form events! the generic parameter is the type of event.target
  //  more info: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/advanced/patterns_by_usecase/#wrappingmirroring
  props: Props & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"button">; // to impersonate all the props of a button element and explicitly not forwarding its ref
  props2: Props & React.ComponentPropsWithRef<MyButtonWithForwardRef>; // to impersonate all the props of MyButtonForwardedRef and explicitly forwarding its ref
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Let's understand JSX.Element vs React.ReactElement vs React.ReactNode step by step:

## `JSX.Element` and `React.ReactElement`

`JSX.Element` and `React.ReactElement` are functionally the same type. They can be used interchangeably.

Consider below example:

```
const element = <div className="greeting">Hello, world!</div>;
```

When the above JSX code runs, it doesn't directly create something you can see on the screen. Instead, it creates a JavaScript object that describes that piece of UI. This object is like a blueprint or a recipe. This is how this blueprint or recipe object will look like:

```
const element = {
  type: 'div',
  props: {
    className: 'greeting',
    children: 'Hello, world!'
  }
};
```

1. **type**: This tells React what type of element we want to create. In this case, it's a `div`.
2. **props**: This is an object that holds all the properties (or "props") that we've passed to our element. Here, we've passed a `className` prop with the value `'greeting'`.
3. **children**: This is a special prop that represents the content inside our element. In this case, it's the string `'Hello, world!'`.

This object is what React uses to understand how to build and update the actual UI on the screen. When React sees this object, it knows to create a div element, give it a class of 'greeting', and put the text 'Hello, world!' inside it.

In a nutshell, we say A ReactElement is an object with a type and props.

## So what is the difference between `JSX.Element` and `React.ReactElement`?

`JSX.Element` is a TypeScript type for JSX expressions, and `React.ReactElement` is a React type for React elements.

## Is this correct?

```
const Component = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: JSX.Element;
}) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};


// Usage

<Component>hello world</Component>
```

In above stated example, TypeScript isn't happy because we declared the type of `children` to be `JSX.Element`, however, we are passing a string ("hello world") which is not a `JSX.Element`. Hence, we need a different type for `children` that can accept string, number, null, ReactElement ....

This is where `React.ReactNode` shines.

## React.ReactNode

As per below definition of `React.ReactNode`.

`React.ReactNode` is a ReactElement, string, number, ReactFragment, ReactPortal, boolean, null & undefined.

```
declare namespace React {
  type ReactNode =
    | ReactElement
    | string
    | number
    | ReactFragment
    | ReactPortal
    | boolean
    | null
    | undefined;
}
```

Example:

```
const Component = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) => {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};


// Usage
<Component> Hello World </Component>
```

Now TypeScript is happy!!

Happy coding!