# Cannot find name React$Node React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I'm adding typescript to my react-native app,

in App.tsx

I'm getting this error on **Cannot find name React$Node** on

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
 ...
}
```

Comment: please accept the appropriate answer to your question.

Answer (score 7):

I'm unsure of the syntax you're using, and not sure where `React$Node` comes from. From my experience, the correct typing and syntax should be `React.ReactNode` or `React.ReactElement`. For example:

```
import React from 'react'

const App = (): React.ReactElement => { 

  return (
    // component code
  )
}
```

As for the difference between `ReactNode` and `ReactElement` (because I wasn't entirely sure), I found ford04's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840095/1125251) useful - quoted here:

> **ReactElement and JSX.Element** are the result of invoking [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)
>   directly or via JSX transpilation. It is an object with `type`,
>   `props` and `key`. [`JSX.Element`]
>
> **ReactNode** is used as return type for `render()` in class components. It also is the default type for `children` attribute with
>   [`PropsWithChildren`]

Comment: I've just looked up `React$Node` - it's a [Flow](https://flow.org) type. So the corresponding type for TypeScript will be `ReactNode` (or `React.ReactNode` if you don't import it). Make sure you install [`@types/react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) and [`@types/react-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-native).