# Is there a type 'Node' on JavaScript / TypeScript? ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a Modal on React and am using TypeScript. I got an error of a 'parameter of type Node' and couldn't figure out what this is (nor subsequently fix my problem).

```
const Modal = ({ children }: { children: any }) => {
  const elRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null); //tried adding'| Node'
  if (!elRef.current) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "modalDiv";
    elRef.current = div;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const modalRoot = document.getElementById("modal");
//Argument of type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
//Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Node'.ts(2345)
    modalRoot!.appendChild(elRef.current);

    return () => modalRoot!.removeChild(elRef.current);
  }, []);

  return createPortal(<div>{children}</div>, elRef.current);
};
```

Comment: There is `ReactNode` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement

Comment: I tried adding ReactNode but that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: To answer the question in the title (which doesn't seem the same as the question in the body), [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) is one of the most basic concepts in HTML manipulation.

Comment: All you're doing doesn't look idiomatic for React. Anyway type error happen because `elRef.current` defined as nullable. You can go with `modalRoot!.appendChild(elRef.current!);` because you're sure it is initialized

Comment: `ReactNode` is not relevant here

Comment: How would I go about solving this? this fix by @AlekseyL. kind of pushes the problem to the useEffect now, stating that ```Argument of type '() => () => HTMLDivElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'. ```

Comment: Please change question title, this is misleading, try to use the TS error and the context.

Answer (score 3):

The problem typescript is signaling here is not about the `Node`. `Node` is a generic DOM element, and `HTMLDivElement` matches correctly. The problem is the `null` value it may assume, and a `null` is obviously not a `Node`, so you cannot use null in `appendChild`.

You should add a check like `if (elRef.current != null) { ... }` in order to ensure the `HTMLDivElement` has been correctly created.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const modalRoot = document.getElementById("modal");
    if (elRef.current) modalRoot!.appendChild(elRef.current);

    return () => {
      if (elRef.current) modalRoot!.removeChild(elRef.current);
    }
  }, []);
```

An easier way (and in this case, a more **logical** one) would be just to use `elRef.current!` to tell TS you are sure that the element is present, and this is clear given your previous code.