# React-Typescript: This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'Element | undefined', but multiple children were provided

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am using react-typescript for my app. For styling I am using Style component. I have decided I will create my custom Hooks Input and Password input. So I first created Input wrapper where I added necessary input fields. After that I have created Password input field. i extended my Password input component props with Input component props. But when I am using Input component wrapper to my password component. I am getting error: `This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'Element | undefined', but multiple children were provided.`

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

**This is my Input wrapper component**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ErrorBoundary from "components/errorBoundary";

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`;

const Label = styled.label<{ minimized?: boolean }>`
  display: block;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.inputLabelColor};
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: ${({ minimized }) => (minimized ? "11px" : "16px")};
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(${({ minimized }) => (minimized ? "9px" : "16px")});
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: transform 150ms linear, font-size 150ms linear;
`;

const Error = styled.p`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.errorTextColor};
`;

const Description = styled.p`
  color: blue;
`;

export interface IInputWrapperProps {
  label?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  minimizedLabel?: boolean;
  description?: string;
  error?: string;
  wrapperStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
  children?: JSX.Element;
}

export default ({
  label,
  error,
  description,
  children,
  required,
  wrapperStyle,
  minimizedLabel
}: IInputWrapperProps) => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary id="InputWrapperErrorBoundary">
      <div style={wrapperStyle}>
        <Container>
          <Label minimized={minimizedLabel}>
            {label} {required && <span style={{ color: "red" }}> *</span>}
          </Label>
          {children}
        </Container>
        {description && <Description>{description}</Description>}
        {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}
      </div>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

**This is my password component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import eyeHide from "./eye-svgfiles/eyeHide.svg";
import eyeShow from "./eye-svgfiles/eyeShow.svg";
import InputWrapper, { IInputWrapperProps } from "../wrapper";
const Passwordinput = styled.input`
  border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.inputBorderColorFaded};
  background: ${({ theme }) => theme.inputBackgroundColor};
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.inputTextColor};
  height: 52px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  &:focus {
    border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.inputBorderColor};
    outline: 0;
  }
`;
const Svg = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 65%;
  transform: scale(0.8);
`;

export interface IPasswordProps extends IInputWrapperProps {
  onChange: (i: string) => void;
  value?: string | undefined;
}
export default ({ onChange, value, label, error, ...rest }: IPasswordProps) => {
  const [state, setstate] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <InputWrapper label={label} error={error} {...rest}> //I am getting error in here 
        <Passwordinput
          label={label}
          type={state ? "text" : "password"}
          onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
          value={value}
          error={error}
        />
        <Svg>
          <img
            onClick={() => setstate(state => !state)}
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            src={state ? eyeShow : eyeHide}
            alt="searchIcon"
          />
        </Svg>
      </InputWrapper>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Write your interface like this:

```
export interface IInputWrapperProps {
  label?: string;
  required?: boolean;
  minimizedLabel?: boolean;
  description?: string;
  error?: string;
  wrapperStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
  children?: JSX.Element|JSX.Element[];
}
```

in fact writing:

```
children: JSX.Element|JSX.Element[];
```

The children can be either a single JSX Element or an array of Elements.

Answer (score 90):

**To all React 18 adopters out there**

If you just upgraded to React 18 and you're like me, you're adding `React.PropsWithChildren<>` everywhere since the types for props no longer imply `children`. If you're finding this thread, you likely ran into what I ran into where one random component gave this error for seemingly no reason, even though it's totally legal to have multiple elements as `children`.

SOLUTION:

Lots of different things can be "react children", including a lot of primitive types, and things like `undefined`, `null`, and `false` just don't render. My component was kind of like this:

```
<Container>
  {maybeNull && <Component notNullThing={maybeNull} />}
  {maybeNull2 && <Component notNullThing={maybeNull2} />}
  {maybeNull3 && <Component notNullThing={maybeNull3} />}
</Container>
```

Turns out, `maybeNull` technically had the type `unknown`, and that threw everything off. I fixed it with `<>{maybeNull && <Component notNullThing={maybeNull} />}</>` (because a single `unknown` is legal for some reason), though I could have done `{maybeNull ? <Component notNullThing={maybeNull} /> : null}` or something similar as well.

I *think* it's because the type of `React.ReactNode` is a big union that includes `ReactFragment`, which is recursively implemented as `Iterable<ReactNode>`. That's why a `ReactNode` can be an array of `ReactNode`s. However, `unknown` means you don't know which of the things in the union it is, so you don't know that it could be `Iterable<ReactNode>`. Some TypeScripty thing like that.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. There's an easier fix: convert `maybeNull` to boolean using `!! maybeNull`

Comment: Encountered this after upgrading React 17 to React 18. Changing `maybeNull &&` to `!!maybeNull &&` solved the error in vscode, but not in the browser JS console until I relaunched the app.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly it for me. In my case it was a createPortal throwing things off.

Comment: This is cool, however now I'm experiencing a flickering when the components change

Comment: solved my problem!! it's so weird

Comment: MVP!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 48):

It can be fixed with:

```
interface InputWrapperProps {
  ...yourProps,
  children?: React.ReactNode
}
```

Hope its helps !

Comment: This is a great answer because the accepted answer can still fail in some standard React use-cases.  Sometimes a child is a boolean!  {variable && <Element />}

Comment: That's clever, but seems like it could cause some trouble down the line. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72392225/1028230), and, from a link on that question, [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72353143/1028230), "_Functional components return ReactElement | null, so it cannot return a bare string or an array of ReactElements. It is a [known](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33006) [limitation](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20544). The workaround is to use Fragments..._"

Comment: This issue still occurs in React 18.

Answer (score 40):

For me variant suggested by shuhat36 works fine. So I just added fragment for chilrens.

Example with error:

```
<div className="container">
   {renderTabs()}
   {renderButtons()}
</div>
```

And the same code but fixed:

```
<div className="container">
   <>
      {renderTabs()}
      {renderButtons()}
   </>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

One way to solve the error is to use a fragment to wrap the component's children. That worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

solvederror: TS2746: This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.

way: added fragment for chilrens.

```js
code: <p>Username: {loading ? 'Loading' : data}</p>
solved: add <></>
solved code: <p>Username: <>{loading ? 'Loading' : data}</></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but just use

```html
export interface YourType {
  type1: string,
}

const YourComponent = ({type1, children}: PropsWithChildren<YourType>) => {
   return <></>
}
```

You shouldn't explicitly type children

Comment: Did some of what you pasted get cut off at the end?

Comment: No, it's useless info, the main point is the typing with PropsWithChildren

Answer (score 1):

Correct practice is the following:

```
interface InputWrapperProps {
  ...yourProps,
  children?: ReactChild | ReactChild[] | ReactChildren | ReactChildren[];
}
```

Servus

Comment: [`ReactChild` is deprecated, isn't it?](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/49eff991e6e1a9b18acd9d3a61816b8433bb7953/types/react/index.d.ts#L220-L223)

Comment: @ChuckWaggon is on the money here, don't use ReactChild or [ReactChildren for that matter](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/49eff991e6e1a9b18acd9d3a61816b8433bb7953/types/react/index.d.ts#L3021).

Comment: Use PropsWithChildren, please, you don't need to type this like that

Comment: And why exactly is this "correct practice"?  There is still no consensus on this in the community.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a comment that I added inside  tag. The comment was something like below. Looks like React treated this comment as a child.

`{/* TODO: Pending work /*}`

After removing this comment, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be triggered if you forget to destructure your props

For example, the following will trigger the `This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'Element | undefined', but multiple children were provided` error:

```
export const MyComponent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = (children) => (
  <div>{children}</div>
);
```

This is because children is actually the props object, but react wo't throw the error until further down. To fix, remember to destructure children out of props:

```
export const MyComponent: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => (
  <div>{children}</div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

wrapping the children within a fragments simply works for me

Answer (score -1):

For me what worked was to change the interface types to say children?: ReactElement|string and put a span around the child elements

Answer (score -2):

It would be correct to use it like this:

```
interface InputWrapperProps {
....
      children?: any;
}
```

Answer (score -9):

The problem is in '{'. inside consumer '{' must on new line.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).