# 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have the following piece of code ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-50beyp?file=/src/App.tsx)):

```
import { ComponentType, ReactNode } from "react";

type DatetimeCell = ({ value }: { value: string }) => ReactNode;

function getDateTimeCell(): DatetimeCell {
  return ({ value }) => value;
}

function buildCell({
  value
}: {
  value: string;
}): ComponentType<{ value: string }> {
  const DateTimeCell = getDateTimeCell();
  return ({ value }) => <DateTimeCell value={value} />;
}
```

When returning in `buildCell` I get the error:

```
'DateTimeCell' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
```

I thought `ReactNode` would be the most general type for valid JSX, but it seems like that is not the case.
Why is `ReactNode` not valid JSX and how can I solve this issue?

**Edit:**
I know that wrapping `value` in React fragments solves the issue. However, in this specific application I need the type `DatetimeCell` to be able to return any valid JSX. So `string` should be included.

Comment: Try ReactElement instead of ReactNode

Comment: That indeed solves the type error. However, it creates a new one. Now I cannot return a string in DatetimeCell.

Answer (score 9):

**Why is ReactNode not valid JSX ??**
=> https://stackoverflow.com/a/72353143/10146901

**and how can I solve this issue?**
=> Just Return `JSX.Element` as function return type.

```
function buildCell({ value }: { value: string }): JSX.Element { // ... my codes }
```

Solution of your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-ybi9j6)

Comment: I opened your solution and there still is an error in `buildCell`s return.

Comment: I think this is what you meant right? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-sugr36
However, it still throws an error.

Comment: @mgottsch `'buildCell' is defined but never used` . This is just a basic warning **not an error**.  Use the `buildCell` function somewhere, this  warning will be gone

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. There is an error in the return function.

'DateTimeCell' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'ReactNode' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.ts(2786)

Comment: This just gives a different error,`Its type 'Element' is not a valid JSX element type`

Answer (score 0):

Part of `ReactNode` type is `undefined`, which is not a valid JSX element I think.

The easiest way to solve the problem would be just to type `DatetimeCell` as Component as well, and always return an element from `getDateTimeCell` - just wrap the result in a fragment.

```
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react';

type DatetimeCell = ComponentType<{ value: string }>;

function getDateTimeCell(): DatetimeCell {
  return ({ value }) => <>{value}</>;
}

function buildCell({ value }: { value: string }): ComponentType<{ value: string }> {
  const DateTimeCell = getDateTimeCell();
  return ({ value }) => <DateTimeCell value={value} />;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why `undefined` is not valid JSX. React does not crash when you use `undefined` as JSX, so why are the typings like this? (see here for proof: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-payne-yx4xes?file=/src/App.js).
In my application, I need `DatetimeCell` to be able to return `string`, so I cannot use your solution (See edit).

Comment: I suspect `undefined` is not allowed just to stop people from forgetting to return something.

Comment: This is bad, because it prevents me from returning props.children since it can be undefined...

Answer (score -3):

When you invoke DateTimeCell it expects a JSX element (ReactNode) to be returned. You are currently returning a string and not a React node in your getTimeCell function. I recommend  typing your functional components using the FC type provided by react as below:

```
import { FC } from "react";

type Props = { value: string };
type DatetimeCell = FC<Props>;

function getDateTimeCell(): DatetimeCell {
  return ({ value }) => <>{value}</>;
}

function buildCell({ value }: Props): DatetimeCell {
  const DateTimeCell = getDateTimeCell();
  return ({ value }) => <DateTimeCell value={value} />;
}

buildCell({ value: "hello" });
```

Comment: `string` is a `ReactNode`
```type ReactNode = ReactElement | string | number | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;``` (from `@types/react`)