# Strange "JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child" error with a component that accepts multiple children?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The `<DialogContent>` accept  multiple children ([example](https://codesandbox.io/s/udu57n?file=/demo.tsx)).

This is causing the error:

```jsx
    <DialogContent dividers>
      {loading && <Stack alignItems='center'>
        <CircularProgress />
      </Stack>}

      {error && <AlertErrorFallback error={error as any} />}

      {undefined !== customer &&
        <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={AlertErrorFallback}>
          <CustomerDetailsList customer={customer} />
        </ErrorBoundary>
      }
    </DialogContent>
```

I have no clue. Removing `{error && ...}` seems to solve the problem. These values come from a custom hook:

```
const { get, loading, error, data: customer } = useCustomer();
```

- `loading` is `true` o `false` depending of the async fetch operation
- `error` is `null` or the `Error` istance if any
- `data` is `undefined` or a `object`

Comment: What's the exact error stack?

Comment: @Arkellys how can I see the stack? It's a TypeScript error, I can only just see that message in the console.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72399362/9718056

Comment: @Arkellys wow. This actually solve the problem. I can't even understand why. Would you like to make an answer?

Comment: Cool! Hum I'm not sure, the answer would be the same as the one I linked. Maybe we can mark this question as duplicate? Even though the accepted answer is not the solution in your case, it's still relevant I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the type of `error` might be `unknown` . you can use use a fragment to wrap the component

**change  :**

```
 {error && <AlertErrorFallback error={error as any} />}
```

**to :**

```
 <>{error && <AlertErrorFallback error={error as any} />}</>
```