# Create react app with typescript: "This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-18

I had created a fresh react project with typescript using the following command:

```
npx create-react-app . --template typescript
```

I am creating a new component in `SchemesSelector.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Scheme {
  id: number,
  display_name: string,
}

export interface Props {
  schemes: Array<Scheme>;
}

const SchemesSelector = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Select Schemes:</p>
      {props.schemes}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SchemesSelector;
```

However I am getting the following error at the `div`'s opening tag:

```
TS2746: This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.
```

The following is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.52.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.52.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^40.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "plugins": [
      "@typescript-eslint",
      "jsdoc"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest",
      "plugin:jsdoc/recommended",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "google"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am fairly new to react. I tried several solutions available online but nothing worked.

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Surround the children part with a fragment so it's one element?  `<>{props.schemes}</>`

Comment: @ScottWeaver Thanks a ton. It worked but I still do not understand how and why. Can you please refer to a link with explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382324/react-typescript-this-jsx-tags-children-prop-expects-a-single-child-of-type