# How to type React children to accept one string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

With this component:

```
<Component>example string</Component>
```

How to work around type `children: "example string"` resulting in the following Typescript error?

> This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type '"example string"' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.ts(2745)

Note: I want a clean API of `<Component>example string</Component>`, not `<Component>{"example string"}</Component>` or `<Component name="example string" />`. Just want to pass the string as child and have autocompletion. Is a simple thing like that not possible in React/Typescript?

---

### More context

It's an icon component that receives the icon name as child ; the name can be any string between "stringA", "stringB", etc.

```
// in the file using the component
<Icon>stringA</Icon>

// in the component file
type IconProps = {
  children: (typeof iconNames)[number]
}

// in another file
export const iconNames = ["stringA","stringB",...,"stringZ"] as const
```

Comment: Maybe you can wrap the string in an array i.e. `<Component>['My String']</Component>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Typescript: This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'Element | undefined', but multiple children were provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382324/react-typescript-this-jsx-tags-children-prop-expects-a-single-child-of-type)

Comment: Change it to `children: string` without the quotation marks?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl The API I want is <Component>something</Component>, it's cleaner for users than having to wrap the string between ['...'] I rephrased my question for more clarity.

Comment: @Prasanna no, it answers the opposite ("expects a single child")

Comment: @DustInComp no, I don't want the type string, I want the type "example string". I rephrased my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to `children: string` without quotation marks to allow any single string, or, if you want the child to be a constant of `"string"`, pass it *as a constant*:

```
<Component>{'string' as const}</Component>
```

Comment: I don't want the type string, I want the type "example string". I rephrased my question for more clarity.
Can't I have a clean API of <A>keyword</A>? Users are gonna use this component...

Comment: @Victor please read the second half of my answer. You can just as well pass `{'example string' as const}` if the props include `{ children: 'example string' }`

Comment: I've read it but I want the API to be <A>keyword</A>, not <A>{"keyword" as const}</A>. Is it not possible with React to have simple thing like that?

Comment: @Victor Why not pass it as `<Icon name="keyword" />`, or export a map of keywords to icon components and use them like `<icon.keyword />`, instead of bastardizing the `children` prop?

Comment: personal preference, it seems cleaner to me. But if it's not possible...

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to define the type of the children prop in your TypeScript component

```
type ComponentProps = {
  children: ReactNode
}

....

const App = () => {
   return (
     <Component>
       {"example string"}
     </Component>
   )}
```

Comment: If you want to be more specific to allow only string, then

`type ComponentProps = {children: string}`

this would help.