# How to render string OR Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The props to a `Row` component in my table is given below:

```
interface props {
    data: Array<string|number> | Array<React.Component>
}
```

I tried using `data.map()` but it gave me errors since data can also contains `React.Component`
How do I render a table row with contents as items of the given array ?

Comment: Are they react components or react elements? That is, is the array `data={[Foo, Bar]}` or `data={[<Foo />, <Bar />]}`?

Comment: Can you share your full code where you have used the map function.

Comment: @cbr It's in the form [<Foo />, <Bar />]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment, you're not actually working with components, but with elements. In this case, you'll want to use `React.ReactElement` instead of `React.Component`. An element is an instance of a component.

```
interface props {
    data: Array<string | number> | Array<React.ReactElement>
}
```

Your use case sounds like you may be just looking for the type for "anything that I can render". In this case, use `React.ReactNode`:

```
interface props {
    data: Array<React.ReactNode>
}
```

If you only want `string | number | React.ReactElement` but not `false`, `true`, `null`, etc., use `React.ReactChild` instead of `React.ReactNode`, as it covers `string | number | ReactElement`

```
interface props {
    data: Array<React.ReactChild>
}
```

For more details about their differences, see [When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58123398/996081)