# Problem moving React Codebase to TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a fairly complete application written in React. To better maintain the codebase going forward, I have decided to migrate the whole project to TypeScript. In my code, I dynamically render a collection of components onto the page based on a selection. In JS, this works flawlessly, but in TS, it throws error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import AppListTable from './AppListTable';
import B from 'B';
import C from 'C';

const COMPONENTS = {
    AppListTable
    B,
    C
}

var selectedComponents = [{component:'A'},{component: 'C'}];

const components = selectedComponents.map( (val,index) => {
        const TempComponent = COMPONENTS[val.component];
        return <Route key={index} exact path={val.url}><TempComponent /></Route>
    })

render ( {components} );
```

Note that I can't share the whole codebase, but this is the part this is having issues. Hovering over **COMPONENTS** give me this error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ AppListTable: () => Element; }'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ AppListTable: () => Element; }'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement

Answer (score 0):

For all who run into this same problem, I ended up doing this to solve the problem.

```
let COMPONENTS: {[name: string]: React.FC} = {};
COMPONENTS[AppListTable.name] = AppListTable;
```

You can now access the component via: `const TempComponent = COMPONENTS[componentName];`