# Rendering a Constant Inside of a React Class Component

Tags: reactjs, constants, rendering

I have a quick question regarding the way to render content using constants in a React class component. So the following code works fine (rendering a constant using the map function):

```
class App extends React.Component {

array = [
   {
      name: "Sarah",
      age: 27
   },
   {
      name: "Sam",
      age: 35
   }
 ]

render() {
  const output = this.array.map(elem => (
      <div>
        <p>{elem.name}</p>
        <p>{elem.age}</p>
      </div>
  ));
    return (
      <div>{output}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, the following produces a blank page (I am simply defining a constant that returns a div and trying to render it):

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const Output = () => (
        <div>Hello</div>
    );
    return (
      <div>{Output}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

But virtually identical code works if instead of the curly braces I use the angular ones:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const Output = () => (
      <div>Hello</div>
    )
    return (
      <div>
        <Output />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So it seems like this has something to do this curly and angular brackets. Curly braces work when I use a map function but do not when I define a constant that returns a div inside a render method and try to render it directly. Then it works again when I use angular brackets... This is kind of strange. I understand that this is far from the most important thing, I'm just trying to get to the bottom of this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular brackets are used to render components. Since you've defined `Output` as a function which returns some JSX, this makes it a function component as far as React is concerned (or rather Babel, which handles the transpilation of your JSX).

You can use curly brackets but then you should change `Output` to a React node. Here's how you'd do that:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const Output = <div>Hello</div>
    return (
      <div>{Output}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement) answer for some clarification regarding the difference between React nodes, elements etc.

Comment: Thank you. So in my example, the reason rendering with map works is because map returns an array or an object which is not a component or a function and can therefore be rendered in curly braces, is this correct?

Comment: Well, `map` will always return a new array. Never an object. Of course, the array can consist of anything, including React components (which are either functions or objects). The question of whether to use curly brace or angle brackets depends on whether you're rendering a node or a component.

Also worth mentioning is that since `output` is a constant you might as well avoid defining it in the render method, since you're then redefining it every time the component (re)renders.

Answer (score 1):

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const Output = () => (
        <div>Hello</div>
    );
    return (
      <div>{Output()}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

if you try to call a function Output() it will return the JSX but follow this [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component) they dont recommend that