# Is there a typing for React Function components that includes returning fragments, nulls, strings etc?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-16

My question is a clarification/update on this highly upvoted question:

[When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement)

It seems to me that TypeScript is not going to play well when you want to have function components that return primitives like string, null etc.

For example, say you have a component that wants a render prop:

```js
import React from "react"; 

type User = {
    id: string; 
    name: string; 
    imgSrc: string; 
}


type UserProfilePageProps = {
    RenderUserPanel: React.ComponentType<{user: User}>; 
}

export const fetchUser = async () : Promise<User> => {
    return {
        id: "123", 
        imgSrc: "placeholdit", 
        name: "Joe Bloggs"
    }
}


const UserProfilePage =  (props: UserProfilePageProps) => {
    const {RenderUserPanel} = props; 
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState<null |User>(null); 

    React.useEffect(()=> {
        fetchUser().then(user => setUser(user)); 
    }, []);

    return <section>
        <h2>User Details</h2>
        {user && <RenderUserPanel user = {user}/>}
    </section> 
}
```

Now I can create components that *should* fulfil this render prop in four different ways:

```js
class ClassBasedUserPanel extends React.Component<{user: User}> {
    render() {
        return <div> 
                {this.props.user.name}
        </div>
    }
}

class ClassBasedUserPanelThatReturnsString extends React.Component<{user: User}> {
    render() {
        return  this.props.user.name; 
    }
}

const FunctionBasedUserPanel = (props: {user: User}) => {
    return <div> 
      {props.user.name}
    </div>
}

const FunctionBasedUserPanelThatReturnsString = (props: {user: User}) => {
    return  props.user.name;
}
```

However, that `FunctionBasedUserPnelThatReturnsAString` does not fit  `React.ComponentType<{user: User}>;`  because `React.FunctionComponent` must return a `React.ReactElement` which a string is not.

`React.ClassComponent` on the otherhand, does not have this constraint.

```js
const Main = () => {
    return <div> 
        <UserProfilePage RenderUserPanel = {ClassBasedUserPanel}/>
        <UserProfilePage RenderUserPanel = {ClassBasedUserPanelThatReturnsString}/>
        <UserProfilePage RenderUserPanel = {FunctionBasedUserPanel}/>
        
        {/* ERROR! */}
        <UserProfilePage RenderUserPanel = {FunctionBasedUserPanelThatReturnsString}/>

    </div> 
}
```

Essentially, what I want is a type that is:

```js
type TypeImLookingFor<P = {}>  = React.ComponentType<P> | (props: P) => ReactNode;
```

Does this exist? Is there a reason that it shouldn't exist?

Note: I'm currently using React 16. Perhaps this is something that is fixed in React 17 or 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post my own best solution for React 16 for this now - but I welcome other answers, especially if there are updates from React 17/18.

The problem with widening the type as I've suggested, is that it doesn't actually work.

As an example:

```js
type TypeImLookingFor<P = {}>  = React.ComponentType<P> | ((props: P) => React.ReactNode); 

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return "aaa"; 
    }
}

const ComponentB = () => {
    return "bbb"; 
}

// They do match the type signature
const A: TypeImLookingFor = ComponentA; 
const B: TypeImLookingFor = ComponentB; 

const Main =  () => {
    return <div> 
        <ComponentA/> 
        
        {/* 
        'ComponentB' cannot be used as a JSX component.
        Its return type 'string' is not a valid JSX element.ts(2786) */}
        <ComponentB/>
    </div>;

}
```

That is, if you want use a function component in a 'JSX-y' fashion - you can't return a string, number etc, even though you could do that with a class component.

The best solution then, in my opinion is:

1. Explicitly state the return type of your function components as `React.ReactElement`
2. If they are returning a string, or a number etc, wrap it in a fragment

```js
const ComponentC = () : React.ReactElement => {
    //Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.ts(2322)
    return "aaa"; 
}

const ComponentD = () : React.ReactElement => {
    return <> aaa </>
}

const Main2 =  () => {
    return <div> 
        <ComponentA/> 
        <ComponentD/>
    </div>;

}
```