# TypeScript Interface Issue with JSX.Element in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to create a type for an array in React but I am getting the below error. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Could anyone please help me find out the thing I am missing?

Thanks

```
interface RowsData {
  [key: string]: string | number | JSX.Element;
}

const rows: RowsData = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A', action: <div style={{ color: 'blue' }}> Hello </div> },
  { id: 2, name: 'B', action: <div style={{ color: 'blue' }}> World </div> },
  { id: 3, name: 'C', action: <div style={{ color: 'blue' }}> Foo </div> }
];
```

**Error**

```
Type '{ id: number; name: string; action: JSX.Element; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Element'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'Element'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Did you mean `const rows: RowsData[] = [...`? i.e. declaring the type of rows as `RowData[]`, ***not*** `RowsData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typing needs to be changed as,

```
interface Row {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  action: React.ReactNode;
}

const rows: Row[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'A', action: <div style={{color: 'blue'}}> Hello </div>},
  {id: 2, name: 'B', action: <div style={{color: 'blue'}}> World </div>},
  {id: 3, name: 'C', action: <div style={{color: 'blue'}}> Foo </div>},
];
```

Comment: Damnn... *facepalm* this is what happens when your brain is dead after hours of coding. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: I think its time for some rest :-)

Comment: Yeah I think the same ;) btw what is the difference between JSX.Element and React.ReactNode and why have you used React.ReactNode?

Comment: This should answer your question in much detail - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement?rq=1