# Typescript error (2345) when pushing element to array of elements(React js)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, components, react-typescript

I'm pretty new to Typescript and I was trying to migrate a component I had on Reactjs to typescript. This component is supposed to receive a number from 0-10 as a prop and according to that number populate an array with stars components which are icons I imported from React icons. once the array is populated is then rendered by the component.
but when I  try to push those elements to the Array typescript throws an error as if those elements were not of type Element neither Jsx.
The only way I found it to work was by setting

```
let starsArray: Element[] | any = [];
```

but my idea was not to leave anything as "any" type;

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BsStarFill } from "react-icons/bs";

interface PropsInterface {
  stars: number;
  big?: boolean;
}

const Stars: React.FC<PropsInterface> = ({ stars, big }) => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState<Element[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let starsArray: Element[] = [];
    let starsAmount: number = Math.round(stars) / 2; //gets rating from props and turns it into integer divided by two (ratings were 1-10 and we needed 1-5 stars);

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      //goes throught 1-5 and if the rating amount is higher or equal on each iteration it pushes a filled star component to  starsArray, else it pushes an empty star
      if (starsAmount > i) {
        starsArray.push(<BsStarFill className="star--filled" key={i} />);
      } else {
        starsArray.push(<BsStarFill className="star--unfilled" key={i} />);
      }
    }

    setArray(starsArray);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={big ? "stars --bigstars" : "stars"}>
      {Object.values(array).map((each) => each)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Stars;
```

these where the lines showing the error with a red underline

```
(<BsStarFill className="star--unfilled" key={i} />)
```

```
(<BsStarFill className="star--filled" key={i} />)
```

these is the complete error :

***Argument of type 'JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 123 more.ts(2345)***

I would really appreciate some help here, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: After trying different solutions I found myself fixing the error by setting array and StarsArray as an array of ReactNodes type;

Starsarray: ReactNode[] = [];

A more general explanation: TypeScript expects you to explicitly define the type of the array elements. The array elements type you declared must match the type TypeScript expects to see. Here is a simple example:

```js
interface ISomething {
    arr: string[]
}

// Somewhere in a class a method uses ISomething interface.
public someMethod(): ISomething['arr'] {
    // Note, if you omit ": ISomething['arr']" in the line below
    // you would face ts2345 error when you push a string into the array later.
    const localArray: ISomething['arr'] = [];
    localArray.push('somestring');
    return localArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the compiler is saying that `<BsStarFill />` is a JSX.Element. But you have declared the array and star arrays as `Element[]` which is a differnt type

```
let starsArray: JSX.Element[] = [];

const [array, setArray] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([]);
```

change these to the proper types and it should compile

[When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement)

this contains more information about jsx element and react element types

Comment: It's curious bc I've tried that already and the error message turns around and tells me that I cant set a Element on a Jsx array;

Comment: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JsxElement'.
  Type 'ReactElement<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'JsxElement': kind, openingElement, children, closingElement, and 25 more.ts(2345)

Comment: interesting, Its working for me here. https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-meninsky-e8z3z?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Im not sure if react-icons comes bundles with its types but you could try installing @types/react-icons to your dev dependencies to make sure they are