# How to create a react component map with correct type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a map of react component with typescript which return the corresponding component based on the key, both Item1 and Item2 are react component.

```
const componentMap: {[key: string]: JSX. Element} = {
 "Item1": Item1,
 "Item2": Item2,
}
```

following is definition of item1 and item2

```
type itemProps = {
  props1: string,
  props2: boolean,
}

export const Item1 = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (<div/>)
}

export const Item2 = (props: itemProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (<div/>)
}
```

[codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-bush-imrun?file=/src/App.tsx:61-153)

But get an alert

```
TS2739: Type 'OverridableComponent<BoxTypeMap<{}, "div">>' is 
missing the following properties from type
 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put all relevant details **in** the question, not just linked. What is `Item1`? What is `item2`? Three reasons not to only put that off-site on codesandbox: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Since this is about TypeScript, it can often be useful to replicate the problem in the [TypeScript playground]() as a [mcve] and then post the full playground code in the question, along with a link to the playground for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need a ReactElement Or ReactNode as type. See [When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement) for when to use which.

Comment: If the answer is in that question, vote to close as a duplicate rather than posting a redundant answer. (I'm not sure that question does answer this one, but if so, that's what to do.)

Comment: Not entirely, but enough of a duplicate to warrant this I think. I flagged it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ReactNode works fine.