# TS2345: Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

> TS2345: Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any,
> any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> |
> ReactElement<any, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) =>
> Component<...>)>[]'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> |
> null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> |
> ReactElement<any, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) =>
> Component<...>)>[]'.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7V1t.png)

Here's my code:

```
import React, {forwardRef, ReactNode} from 'react';

import {mergeClasses} from '../../utils';
import {ArrowLeft} from '../../icons';

import {BreadcrumbsProps} from './declarations/Breadcrumbs.types';

import defaultClasses from './styles/Breadcrumbs.module.css'

export const Breadcrumbs = forwardRef<HTMLLabelElement, BreadcrumbsProps>(
    ({
        separator="/",
        children,
        back,
        classNames,
        onClick,
     }) => {
        const styles = mergeClasses(defaultClasses, classNames);

        const Back = (
            <button className={styles.back} type='button' onClick={onClick}>
                <ArrowLeft/>
                <span>Back</span>
            </button>
        )

        const Separator = <span className={styles.separator}>{separator}</span>;

        const getValidChild = (itemToRender: ReactNode, delta: number, index: number) => {
            const SeparatorWithKey = React.cloneElement(Separator, { key: `${index}_separator` });

            return index === 0 ? [itemToRender] : [SeparatorWithKey, itemToRender];
        };

        const getItemsByChildren = () => {
            const delta = React.Children.toArray(children).length;
            return (
                React.Children.map(children, (child: React.ReactElement, index) => {
                return (
                    child &&
                    getValidChild(
                        React.cloneElement(child),
                        delta,
                        index
                    )
                );
            }));
        };

        return (
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
                {back && Back}
                <ul className={styles.breadcrumbs}>
                    {getItemsByChildren()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    },
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You've declared the type of `child` wrong here:

```
React.Children.map(children, (child: React.ReactElement, index) => {
```

`children` is of type `React.ReactNode`. `React.Element` is [something entirely different.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement)

You don't need to type this argument at all, `React.Children.map` already can infer the correct type here. Just this works just fine:

```
React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBm0A7ilACbL5wC+BUEIcARFKhkwNwBQXwAdjCRR86JHABCrFGTRQAriABGAZwAK9MMtxc4cZQyTqIYAFx6YUfgHMu1Hmgh9l8AGIQIcALwFipCknwAHgAJABUAWQAZSJRFJAAbAFF4pBAkAWxJVBl5JTUNZQA+AApivDQAC2B4slY+GgBKL0LtXVYYOSh6wMKdXVxENhgAOgBhKpq64ZAUMGLK6tr07HmJsmx+MiQADybPFrk+Lfx+JDImu11AgHpe6gagA)

Comment: The playground is broken with error: `Property 'children' does not exist on type 'BreadcrumbsProps'.`

Comment: Yea, it should be: 
`const Foo = forwardRef<HTMLLabelElement, BreadcrumbsProps>(({ ...children })`

Answer (score 1):

Check your `tsconfig.json` options and I hope this helps you, because I spent a ton of time before that error, that doesn't make any sense, led to to this article that helpend me to find the source of the issue

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "react": ["node_modules/@types/react"]
    }
  }
```

or

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node"],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es2021"
  },
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems there is a problem for the build to find the types. Are you in a monorepo?

Comment: Yes, this ts conf from my monerepor project, but please note: i just recently had exact same issue, with same ts errors and the issue was that i had two packages installed, that had conflicting type definitions. Specifically i have @mui/core v6 and @mui/style v5. They removed styled component from version 6