# How to use Protected Routes with react-router-dom V6 and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a protected route to only allow logged in users to access my app. The code I have written seems to work, I am redirected to my login page when I try to access the homepage without being logged in, however once I am logged in I can access the page but I does not render and I get the following error: [Click here for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnI8V.png)

I have tried multiple methods and wrapping the element in my protected route seems like the V6 way of doing things, however it doesn't seem to work for me:

My protected route

```
interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
}

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({...rest}) => {
    const auth = useAuth();

    if (auth?.user === null) {
        return <Navigate to='/'/>;
    }
    return <Route {...rest}/>;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

My app (route usage)

```
function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
      API
        .get('api', '/reservation', {})
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response);
        });

    }, [])
    return (
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<LoginPage />}/>
          <Route path='/consultAndReserve' element={<PrivateRoute><Navbar/><ConsultReserve/></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path='/consultAndReserve/:date' element={<><Navbar/><ConsultReserveWithDate/></>}/>
          <Route path='/myReservations'  element={<><Navbar/><Reservations/></>}/>
          <Route path='/tracing'  element={<><Navbar/><Tracing/></>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of images of your code you should include them in your question as properly formatted and readable code snippets.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your suggestion, I have modified my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's fairly trivial to create a "PrivateRoute" component, even in TypeScript.

In your case you can't directly render a `Route` component as the error points out. This was a breaking change between RRDv5 and RRDv6. You can render the `children` prop since you are directly wrapping the components you want to protect.

Example:

```
const PrivateWrapper = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return auth?.user ? children : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
};
```

Usage:

```
<Routes>
  ...
  <Route
    path="/consoleAndReserve"
    element={(
      <PrivateWrapper>
        <Navbar />
        <ConsultReserve />
      </PrivateWrapper>
    )}
  />
  ...
</Routes>
```

Comment: I think I understand what my issue is. The problem is that I am trying to render a Route with my PrivateRoute, which I am not allowed to do. With your method, I would only redirect the user to said page using Navigate instead of a Route? I tried applying your code to mine and I get the following line: JSX element type 'PrivateWrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Comment: @ginoboy Ok, so this is where my minimal experience with Typescript shows through. Let me play around to see if I can get a correct typing for this.

Comment: @ginoboy `React.FC<any>` is very general, but works for a general auth wrapper.

Comment: `const PrivateWrapper = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {` should do it.  That requires that `children` is a `JSX.Element` (more specific than `ReactNode`).  You need that type in order to `return children` directly because a component can only return `JSX.Element | null`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Ah, ok, so the initial answer was *close*. Thanks!

Comment: Drew's revised answer did the trick for me. What is the advantage of using JSX.Element over ReactNode?

Comment: @ginoboy This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement) cleared a bit of it up for me.