# Curly-bracket insertion is "Element" in Typescript, which doesn't allow empty/null options?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-typescript

Given a React component within a Next.js application that has a sub-section that can be set to something, or not, storing it in a variable like this:

```
export const MyComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  let [result, setResult] = useState<ReactNode>()

  async function doFetch() {
    // ... await some API call
    setResult('Successful result!')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={doFetch}>Go</button>
      { result }
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `ReactNode` type allows for the variable to be a JSX element, a string, or `null`/`undefined`. However, the curly-brace insertion gets typed as `Element`, and I get an error that `ReactNode` cannot be assigned to an `Element` type, because `undefined` cannot be cast to a `ReactElement<any, any>` type.

The error is appearing in my Visual Studio IDE, and when doing a `npx next build` with the library dependencies of:

```
"@types/react": "18.0.20",
"@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
"next": "12.3.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0"
"typescript": "4.8.3"
```

Is my type-setting on `useState` wrong? Or is something misconfigured that is forcing inline-expressions to be `Element` types (non-null) versus `ReactNode` types?

Answers on other React/Typescript questions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/72353143/144756 imply the type of an inline expression should be `ReactNode`, but my setup is declaring it as `Element`. Did something change with a recent version of React or Next?

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Do you want the compiler to error when doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement?

Comment: @caTS The compiler is erroring (saying `result` needs to be an `Element`, and `ReactNode` doesn't cut it), but from how React works, I think it should be valid (it skips rendering null/undefined elements like that). The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123882/144756 indicates inline expressions like this should be `ReactNode` types, but `@types/react` 18.0.20 is making them `Element` instead?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is instead of using `string` or `null` options as part of the application flow, wrap them in React Fragments, such that they're always a `JSX.Element`, which makes Typescript happy:

- `null`/`undefined` => `<></>`
- String 'foo' => `<>foo</>`

```
export const MyComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  let [result, setResult] = useState<JSX.Element>(<></>)

  async function doFetch() {
    // ... await some API call
    setResult(<>'Successful result!'</>)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={doFetch}>Go</button>
      { result }
    </div>
  )
}
```

This doesn't get at the root issue of why the curly-brace inline expression is being forced to be a `JSX.Element` type rather than `ReactNode`, and it seems like unnecessary boilerplate, but it does work around this error, if no other better solutions exist.

This workaround is suggested in [this similar GitHub issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/18051#issuecomment-644954717), and cites it cannot be fixed until [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699) gets resolved in the upstream TypeScript library.