# Difference between extending Component and ReactNode

Tags: reactjs

I've seen the following ways to define a react class component, can someone explain what's their difference?

```
class ReactTooltip extends Component { ... }

class ReactTooltip extends React.ReactNode { ... }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement)