# Typescript error around using generics using extends {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
type List<T> = {
  items: T[];
  clickHandler: (a: T) => void;
};

const List = <T extends {}>({
  items,
  clickHandler,
}: List<T>) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={() => clickHandler(item)}>
          {item} // error is showing here
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

typescript Error
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, propsts(2322)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you want to render the items of type T. You have to ensure react that T is "renderable type".

One way to do this is:

```js
const List = <T extends ReactNode>
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're rendering items as children of `div` you can also define it as

```
const List = <T extends JSX.IntrinsicElements['div']['children']>(
```

which internally is defined as `React.ReactNode` would result in the same as @Svetoslav Retkov's answer

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4AFHMAZwB4AVOJADxhIAdgBM2cAFIBlABoA6AJJCYUYELbA0AUQA2SEMJhsA2vhHAAbvgC6ptAAtgOkUSE2AfHAC8cAN5U4OGBBEDYALjguY2sKSkC0HU0AawAJFFE9KAiAChQIrgBKb08LCGARWIBfWKo0CHV4ABlgNngfbl4BYTFJWUVlVXVNXX1DEzNLGztHZ1cPbP84oJC2ABoAuATktIykKHXKSoiWCHZudyKvT0XAohgAVyghOGyNwI5zC3c3wL9g-TYchAKDA2Wy-xAqyCon4l08ryWv1+H0scCSSFoXl8ahE-EqcHqAGFEmgkljsnDNiTUukRJlwSECpVvoikb9sSF8QB6Lm8KA4KBBcRsewQADuagA5nB7HskD8kRwuZ8WWy4AUmT8lSqNgUqjVKPxILA4LjMCh7jomi0YLEgA)