# Typescript: Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component declared as following:

```
const Wrapper = ({children}: {children: ReactElement[]}): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

This wrapper expects an array of ReactElement, for example:

```
<Wrapper>
  {items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Item />
    )
  })}
</Wrapper>
```

This works fine, but when I want to add a div to the returned items list like following:

```
<Wrapper>
   <div /> {/* empty div for the first column */}
  {items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Item />
    )
  })}
</Wrapper>
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>'.ts(2322)
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Here is a good read about different types:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type for `children` in the usual Rect component sense is `ReactNode` (note it's not an array):

```typescript
const Wrapper = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }): ReactElement => {
    return <div className="wrapper">{children}</div>;
};

const Item = () => <div />;

const items = [1, 2, 3];
const x = (
    <Wrapper>
        <div />
        {items.map((item, index) => {
            return <Item />;
        })}
    </Wrapper>
);
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYCiANkiEgHZb7owByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcARFAIw+AbgBQYtBAoBneAHUoKMGCRQ4AXjgAKPGgAWwYo0EU2ALlxwDRk5UvJaDZmwCUDoSTKV4GgHy4YnDBcIIwAK5QZgA8jMAAbtbEKDIydCjkGnwA7koqanx+ODbGpqzRAPRx8X7irOKS0nJwAJIwZJo6rpoBsQlwFbUSUrLwwO0gMp0A2gCM2ABM2ADMALriI80AHp3aQSHRisqqUH77IQfVA2cXFzjjZDIAdCDK2toPINjAFMxb3f5ArdgaEkBEonBom0OoNxCC3KxzpCKkd8qcxK4REA)