# How to add props/attributes to children by looping over them in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way of adding props/attributes to children by looping over `children`?

```
function Comp({ children }) {
  children.forEach((child) => {
    ...
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `children` in React is `React.ReactNode` which is not necessarily an array, it could also be a primitive type like number, string or boolean, as well as a single React Element. (see its type in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123882/13167852).
You need to make sure to account for these cases.

You can't mutate props in React, including the special `children` prop, but you can create new components from them. You can do so with React's `createElement` function, which takes a component type ( a string) as first param (like `"div"`, `"button"` or `"MyReactComponent"`), and a props object as second param. You can then spread the props of the child, and overwrite and/or add any other props you want

A (not complete) working example:

```js
const Comp = ({ children }) => {
  if (
    typeof children == 'string' ||
    typeof children == 'boolean' ||
    typeof children == 'number'
  ) {
    return <>{children}</>;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    return (
      <>
        {children.map((child) =>
          React.createElement(child.type, {
            ...child.props,
            someProp: 'foo',
          })
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
  return React.createElement(children.type, {
    ...children.props,
    someProp: 'foo',
  });
};

const SomeChild = ({ someProp }) => <div>{someProp}</div>;

const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <Comp>
      <SomeChild someProp="asd" />
      <SomeChild someProp="asd" />
      <div>asd</div>
    </Comp>
  </div>
);
```

In this example, even though we passed `"asd"` for `someProp`, that got overwritten to `"foo"` inside `Comp`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that. However, you shouldn't use `.forEach` for that. What you need is [`Children.map`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children) and [`cloneElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement) provided by React (and [react-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is) package to check if child is React element).

```
import React, {Children, cloneElement} from 'react';
import {isElement} from 'react-is';

function Comp({ children }) {
  return (<div>
    {Children.map(children, (el) => {
      if (!isElement(el)) return el; // Skip non-elements
      return cloneElement(el, {style: {color: 'red'}});
    })}
  </div>);
};
```