# How can I type a generic function in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-constraints

Given the following types and components:

```
interface Widget { type: string; }
interface TextField extends Widget { type: 'TextField'; textValue: string; }
interface Checkbox extends Widget { type: 'Checkbox'; booleanValue: boolean; }

type Props<W extends Widget> = { widget: W; }
type WidgetComponent<W extends Widget> = (props: Props<W>) => React.ReactNode;

const TextfieldComponent: WidgetComponent<TextField> = ({ widget }) => { return <input type="text" /> };
const CheckboxComponent: WidgetComponent<Checkbox> = ({ widget }) => { return <input type="checkbox" />};
```

and the following predicates:

```
const isTextfield = (widget: Widget): widget is TextField => widget.type === 'TextField';
const isCheckbox = (widget: Widget): widget is Checkbox => widget.type === 'Checkbox';
```

How can I type properly the given function?

```
const factory = <W extends Widget>(widget: W): WidgetComponent<W> | null => {
    if (isTextfield(widget)) {
        return TextfieldComponent;
    } else if (isCheckbox(widget)) {
        return CheckboxComponent;
    }
    return null;
}
```

TypeScript does not like that and it tells me:

```
Type 'WidgetComponent<TextField>' is not assignable to type 'WidgetComponent<W>'.
  Type 'W' is not assignable to type 'TextField'.
    Property 'textValue' is missing in type 'Widget' but required in type 'TextField'.(2322)
```

I understand why TypeScript is giving me this error but I don't know which mechanism should I use to give TypeScript the proper type constraints.

You can see it in action on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgHVgATAcyXgG84YATzBIAXHADOMKDU6k4AXyq16jNMwAqSAB4wAYsCQAbdnB11q7Caw7c+A4WIJbdB4+zIDzANRRGArk5SMtRyisp0DExwAMIAFkhoANYARhDaZrpIltZsXDxw-EIi4vjxianpnmkQRqjUvgFONXUo1PJK5MXMAAo4YBIAPCyZFlY2+TAAfHAAvIVwAO62POIsHV2OE3YxuJDU2TDDo9njeXYz8wAUYP0S4n0QA8NTAJRzM8joMAB0XxgAOQg7CQFHIaAg1CkcBcMEwhhMu3AkMOaxWMCR+0Og1hbhMlzgV34y0minesxm-CIMH8UGocEGNDA-ng3VmACI6Lp2XAAPQzBQUCFQ+DlZJpbSYlG0NGTKUHWiDMWVbQEolLdFkj4Lam0+mM6jM1mODloBLi9I8-mCyjC6HACSw+HuOaEkl2WV2V7id0FB0w8x40wUjWTH7dOazeb4XEIjxCyH2iTKiWuq6+mCenje0N2OD+lPpbUZ8NbKPRwvaMiUci83msOIoeASOIQfwmOApZgwBIOERwCCYARxf1qGDQQRwTD+agYYCQgD84MTWG+E9dx3Mp1y6Km6fRaxz5x48uxLBmAB84NR20ZtbxyHAn-mh1cHU64-vJq93g-n-+4F1OkA10Z1ET2aUYAof8FDMIwJGYYBXwdSsvy9X9HwAp8gPpStT1oaDnyUf8cOvW8KE6O1WXMMD2HEWMXXmIpHFKBiTHwAAaLxdEaQJSh+AT8EUBMRW4uE43wzNthPCCFSONj2EvMijDveYxwnK4uXE9xXhEiRaiQH4jAgThNJoiTZMOOAAEIo2UoxdKAA)

Comment: Can't your factory function returns the rendered element instead ?
`if (isTextfield(widget)) { return <TextfieldComponent widget={widget} />;`

Comment: I wonder why the first line says that `A<B>` is not assignable to `A<C>` but the second like says that `C` is not assignable to `B`. I would expect that `B` has to be assignable to `C` and not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using function [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

```
// Overload signature (no body)
function factory(widget: TextField): WidgetComponent<TextField>;

// Overload signature (no body)
function factory(widget: Checkbox): WidgetComponent<Checkbox>;

// Implementation signature (with function body)
function factory(widget: TextField | Checkbox) {
  if (isTextfield(widget)) {
    return TextfieldComponent;
  } else if (isCheckbox(widget)) {
    return CheckboxComponent;
  }
}
```

The solution is hard to scale if you have many types of `Widget`, as you need an overload for each of them, but it should be fine for your case.

You can test with:

```
const myTextField: TextField = { type: 'TextField', textValue: 'foo' };
const myCheckbox: Checkbox = { type: 'Checkbox', booleanValue: true };

const textFieldComp = factory(myTextField);
const checkboxComp = factory(myCheckbox);
```

Your IDE type hint should correctly identify `textFieldComp` as `WidgetComponent<TextField>` and `checkboxComp` as `WidgetComponent<Checkbox>`

---

P.S: You should probably be using  `ReactElement | null` as the return type for your `WidgetComponent` function component. Using `ReactNode` will give you trouble when rendering JSX. See, for instance: [When to use JSX.Element vs ReactNode vs ReactElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123398/when-to-use-jsx-element-vs-reactnode-vs-reactelement)