# How to convert HTMLElement to JSX.Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here I have something like below as HTMLElement

```
<div id='hiddenDiv'>
  <div>foobar</div>
</div>
```

And I am doing something like below trying to convert it into JSX.Element:

```
function renderMailCompose(): JSX.Element {
    const content = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');
    return content;
}
```

but I am getting the error

> Type 'HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type
> 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

I am wondering how I can properly convert the div including all its content to JSX.Element. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I know this is from a string, but could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675652/proper-typescript-type-for-creating-jsx-element-from-string

Answer (score 0):

Generally, unless you have a specific reason for using `getElementById`, what we usually want to do in-order to store elements inside variables in React, is to use the built-in `useRef` hook.

So you can do this -

```js
const hiddenDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

return (
  <div ref={hiddenDivRef}>
    <div>foobar</div>
  </div>
);
```

After which we can access the value like this -

```js
console.log(hiddenDivRef.current);
```

You can also use all the relevant functions you would normally have,
i.e. - `.focus()`, etc...

- Note: The hook is not exclusive to storing elements.

Answer (score -2):

You can use html-react-parser to render html like this:

```sh
npm install html-react-parser --save
```

```js
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

function renderMailCompose(): JSX.Element {
    const content = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv');
    return parse(content.innerHTML);
}
```